# How to do SQL Server rounding digit by digit?

Tags: sql, sql-server

A consultant has described a type of rounding I need to use in a financial application.

The following value: 0.01488

needs to be rounded in steps like this. We round each digit at a time,

```
0.0148 -> 0.015
0.015 -> 0.02
```

Thus the result is 0.02 (2 cents).

But if we did normal rounding to 2 dp the value 0.0148 would round to 0.01.

What is the name of this rounding? And how can I do it with SQL Server?

**Update:**

My example above is an arbitrary example. The starting value might be 0.15436798, i.e. any number of decimal places. It is related to the result of a previous multiplication. In that case I would need to round more times.

Comment: `But if we did normal rounding to 2 dp the value 0.0148 would round to 0.01` - that is not rounding, that is a truncation.

Comment: Truncation? Not really. If I do this, declare @value float = 0.01488 select ROUND(@value, 2) the result comes out to 0.01. That is rounding to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a scalar function to do this job.
like:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_roundx]( @num FLOAT,@round INT) 
   RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count INT=10;

    WHILE @count > = @round
       BEGIN
          SET @num = ROUND(@num,@count);
          SET @count=@count-1;
       END;
    RETURN @num 
END
```

And then use it as per your conveneince for any depth of rounding you want?
For example

```
DECLARE @num FLOAT=0.014887;    
SELECT @num AS ActualNumber,dbo.fn_roundx(@num,2) AS RoundedNumber
```

[image]

or

```
DECLARE @num FLOAT=0.014887;  
SELECT @num AS ActualNumber,dbo.fn_roundx(@num,3) AS RoundedNumber
```

[image]

Sounds good?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like following?

```
DECLARE @num decimal(20,5)=0.014880;
DECLARE @count INT=5;
DECLARE @round INT=2;

SELECT @num value;

WHILE @count > = @round
BEGIN
   SET @num = ROUND(@num,@count);
   SET @count=@count-1;
END;

SELECT @num value;
```

with following output..

[image]

for any number up to any number of `round` you want?

Comment: And you can put this into a function to use this as per user requirement?

Comment: Is there an easy way to take the original value and determine what we should set count to? For instance the original value might be 0.1543678, so we would need to set @count to be 7 (if I understand correctly).

Comment: the function code written in my other answer should handle any decimal points up to 10 I believe. and you can always add more decimal places. and can change the data type from FLOAT to DECIMAL etc?

Comment: and yes.. @count=6 or 7 or whatever should handle that situation.

Comment: But can I take a value 0.12343452435 and get a count out of that for how many roundings I should do? Or do you just think I should fix it at the max value? decimal(20,10) I should set the @count to 10?

Comment: try that? Ideally, any number should work. and setting up a maximum will not even harm as in first go, the code will round up to that many decimal places and then will start rounding downward.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROUND` function twice

First time pass length as `3` to round `0.01488` to `0.01500`

```
SELECT Round(0.01488, 3) -- 0.01500
```

On top of it pass length as `2` to round `0.01500` to `0.02000`

```
SELECT Round(0.01500, 2) -- 0.02000
```

finally it should be something like this

```
DECLARE @num NUMERIC(16, 5) = 0.01488

SELECT Round(Round(@num, 3), 2)
```

Comment: Note: this would only work for numbers with 4 decimal places to begin with. e.g. It would break for a number like 0.01448 (which, by the OP's steps, should round up to 0.02 like 0.01448 -> 0.0145 -> 0.015 -> 0.02)

Comment: @ZLK - OP skipped the last 8 in example conversion so I assume we need to round it from 3 decimal place

Comment: Sure. But the OP asked for the name of the rounding and how to do it in SQL, so I assume that example is just an example and it could require rounding (n - 2) times, where _n_ is the number of decimal places that could theoretically be anything.

Comment: @ZLK - Fair enough.. Lets wait for OP

Comment: Yes, it could be any number of decimal places to begin with, e.g. 0.154367 or 0.5643453453. It is purely related to the result of a previous multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select round(round(0.01500,3),2)
select round(round(0.01488,3),2)
```